# How to fetch select set of elements on a REST call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest

`GET /users/1` - Fetches all attributes of an user

How to selectively fetch a user attribute? (say first-name)

```
GET /users/1/first-name 
or
GET /users/1?first-name
```

How to selectively fetch a user attribute? (say last-name)

```
GET /users/1/last-name 
or
GET /users/1?last-name
```

How to selectively fetch a user attribute? (say first-name, last-name)

```
GET /users/1?first-name&last-name - In this scenario, I cannot use the first approach to get 2 attributes
```

What pattern would be preferable in the above approach
I intend to pass the column names, not sure if this is a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

One way I can think of is to have a `attributes` param in the request url which can have the comma-separated attributes to be fetched:

```
GET /users/1?attributes=first_name,last_name,age
```

Then, in your controller's `show` action:

```
def show  
  attributes_to_fetch = params[:attributes].split(',')
  @user = User.select(attributes_to_fetch).find(params[:id])  
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You can pass attributes in params, which you want to select. like following in url:

```
GET /users/1?attrs=first_name,last_name,email
```

Then, in your controller write following code.

```
def show  
  attrs = params[:attrs].split(',')  
  @user = User.select(attrs).find(params[:id])  
end
```